# egit plugin in Eclipse: how to use it

Tags: git, eclipse

I am having troubles in understanding how to use the egit plugin in Eclipse for resolving conflicts in `git merge` operations.

I think I understood the various "merge modes" from this link https://enji.systems/2022/09/30/eclipse-merge-mode.html

**Question 1**
Are these "merge modes" basically just "viewing modes" of the conflicts?
[image: egit merge modes]

**Question 2**
a) does "use the git "pre-merged" ours version of conflicting files" correspond to a viewer that shows the last version of the branch I am merging into without any automatically inferred ok changes from git?

b) does "use the working tree version of conflicting files (pre-merged by git)" correspond to the file I normally see, with changes without conflicts automatically applied?

I use the second "use the working tree version ..." in order to look only at conflicts.

**Question 3**
What is the exact meaning of "next difference" vs "next change"?

**Question 4**
I see how to copy the (incoming) changes from right to left, but I do not see any items to say "keep local version". How am I supposed to tell egit to keep the local changes and discard the incoming ones? Do I need to delete the lines between the conflict markers? Isn't there any automatic ways of doing it?

**Question 5**
I think the official documentation of egit is here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide
but it seems outdated since the list of merge modes is different to the one I see in (my up-to-date) Eclipse (section "Using merge tool").
Is there any up-to-date link for the doc?

Sorry for all these question, but the most important one is the fourth, because I would really rather not delete the conflicting lines one by one.

Comment: Question 6 would better be asked in Software Recommendations I feel. There are already lots of questions packaged into one here.

Comment: This dialog is for merge conflicts only for the initial content of the diff editor. Just tick _Don't ask again_ and click _OK_ if you don't understand it.

Comment: @kutschkem Question 6 is based on false assumptions and on not knowing EGit.

Comment: @kutschkem I removed question 6.

Comment: @howlger I agree I do not know egit. Indeed I always use VSC for resolving conflicts, but in this case I cannot. Documentation does not help. I could not find anything on "next diff"/"next change" for example.

Comment: It is difficult to help [because you do not describe your real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Yes, VS Code and EGit are different (VS Code provides a frontend for the command line Git, whereas EGit is based on JGit not have these limits). The documentation is built-in and generally not outdated (otherwise report it, best with a patch). In Eclipse, common Git related things are done in the _History_ and the _Git Staging_ views and many functions can be accessed via the right-click menu (which can be applied to multiple selected files at once).

Comment: I made a list of question. Any answer would be helpful.

Comment: Please focus on one thing. 1+2: no (see my first comment), 3: depends on the context 4: see right-click menu in the _Git Staging_ view (see my previous comment), 5: as far as I know, this is the source for the current documentation shipped with Eclipse (_Help > Help Contents_); please report the outdated parts to EGit (best with a patch), which does not mean that the documentation is generally outdated.